# Quieten Visual Studio's cl.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, command-line

When compiling from the command line with `cl.exe` the name of the source file is printed by the compiler:

```
c:\bar> cl /nologo foo.cpp
foo.cpp
```

Is it possible to require `cl.exe` to not print that irrelevant info?

A test suite here invokes `cl.exe` with arbitrary source file names and it would be nice if `cl` remained silent when there is no diagnostics to emit.

Comment: Just redirect output to a file or the NUL device.

Comment: I'm interested on the rest of the output (diagnostics, mostly) so redirecting is not an option. The last resort is filtering the line with the source file name, but that's ugly and probably a bug breeder.

Comment: The file that's getting compiled is part of the diagnostics, shows you which particular translation unit has the problem.  If you just want to see errors then redirect stdout but not stderr.  It is very unclear why you like to run the compiler from the command line, most users use an IDE.  Very well supported by MSVC.